# How to draw an image with matrices with coordinate and grayscale matrices

Tags: image, matlab, graph, matrix, draw

Hi I am trying to draw an image.

I have three matrices:

> Matrix A: X coordinates
>
> Matrix B: Y coordinates
>
> Matrix C: Image gray scale

X, Y coordinates can be integer, decimal points, or NaN.
If any of the matrix point is NaN, I will not draw that point.

For example:

```
A = [1, 1;     B = [1, 2;       C = [1, 2;
     2, 2;          1, 2;            3, 4;
    NaN,3 ]         4, 4 ]           5, NaN]
```

I will plot a point with value of `C(1)` at `X(1)`, `Y(1)`. Value 1 is drawn at `(1,1)` Value 2 is drawn at `(1,2)` Value 3 is drawn at `(2,1)` Value 4 is drawn at `(2,2)`

However, `B(3,1)` and `C(3,1)` are not used because `A(3,1)` is NaN. Also, `A(3,2)` and `B(3,2)` are not used because `C(3,2)` is `NaN`.

Any suggestion or help to implement this function?.. I appreciate any comments or suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
% filter out the data with NaN's
idx_filter = ~(isnan(A)|isnan(B)|isnan(C));

% create a color map
cmap = gray(256);

% plot using scatter (36 is default size)
scatter(A(idx_filter),B(idx_filter),36,cmap(C(idx_filter),:))
```

The colours now still all look kinda just black, because you're using just a small part of the whole 1-256 range.

Comment: Nice, beat me by seconds. You actually don't need the vectors, I think `isnan` works just as well on the Matrix.

Comment: yeah, because of the logical indexing, that'll automatically transform everything to vector. I'll throw it out

Comment: Hi I tried your code, and I am getting an error 'Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.' for the last line. Any idea what could be causing this? Is it because I have negative values for A and B?... or maybe my C is a value between 0~1. Maybe I should change this to integer somehow... Ima try to google to change my 0~1 scale to 0~256

Comment: I dont think my C matrix is the problem. I tried 0~1 scale and 0~256 scale but still gives me the same error =(

Comment: I assumed your C-matrix was 1-256 integer, it indexes right into the colormap index `cmap`. Since indexes are 1-based integers, that zero threw you off.